# ¿Cómo crear una colección de personalizada de productos en tiendas Jumpseller (Liquid)?

Tags: liquid

Estoy desarrollando una plantilla para una tienda de Jumpseller que utiliza bootstrap 4 con liquid para el FrontEnd y tengo la necesidad de crear colecciones personalizadas que me permitan llamar a ese grupo de productos en distintas vistas de la tienda, de la siguiente forma:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
  {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Actualmente cuento con la colección "Featured" que se puede aplicar a cada producto chequeando una opción en el panel de gestión y "Latest", que se crea de forma automática con las cargas recientes. Sin embargo, necesito poder crear más colecciones para poder materializar la lógica de negocio de la tienda sin que interfiera con el árbol de categorías de los productos.

De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de generar una colección personalizada es crear una categoría. Veo que el problema en la categoría sería justamente que tienes un menú de navegación calculado de forma automática a partir del árbol de categorías de tu tienda y que naturalmente esto podría ser un problema a la hora de utilizar categorías para crear colecciones.

Ante esto tienes varias alternativas:

1. La más simple, por ejemplo si el nombre de tu categoría es "Colección 1", puedes insertar en el loop que genera el menú una condición para que se la salte, como por ejemplo:

   {%  if cat.name == "Colección 1 % }
   {% continue %}
   {% endif %}
2. La más compleja, pero más sostenible en el tiempo. Utiliza los menús de navegación nativos en vez un menú automatizado. Revisa este video de ejemplo para crear un menú: http://recordit.co/QR1z5BPFs5

Luego puedes utilizar los items del menú como por ejemplo así en la página donde quieres ponder el menú:

```
 {% for item in menu.the_menu.items %}
 {% include 'navigation_menu' with item %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Y así debiese verse el parcial navigation_menu:

```
<li class="nav-item {% if item.dropdown %}dropdown{% endif %} {% if active_items contains item.id %}active{% endif %}">
  <a href="{{ item.url }}" {% if item.external %}target="_blank"{% endif %} title="{{item.name}}" class="{% if item.dropdown %}dropdown-toggle {% endif %}level-1 trsn nav-link" {% if item.dropdown %}data-toggle=""{% endif %}>{{ item.name }}</a>
  {% if item.dropdown %}
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
      {% for item in item.items %}
        {% include 'navigation_menu' with item %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
</li>
```

- Si te das cuenta este parcial se llama a si mismo para crear los elementos del submenú. Puedes ver un ejemplo de cómo funciona esto directamente en el tema SIMPLE (que utiliza la ultima versión de bootstrap), si quieres puedes crear una tienda de pruebas con otro email y puedo agregarte varios meses gratis para que la utilices para experimentar.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias @PaperBirdMasterya lo eliminé.